# Trying to get an firestore snapshot with an type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get some formatted data from firestore but i'm getting this error:

Another exception was thrown: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Store' in type cast

Here is my class code.

```
class StoreInterface {
  String name;
  String address;
}

class Store{

  Store data;

  Store.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){

    StoreInterface data = snapshot.data as StoreInterface
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snapshot.data` is a `Map<String, dynamic>`, which cannot be cast to `StoreInterface`.

I would suggest adding a constructor to `StoreInterface` which takes a map in.

```
class StoreInterface {

  String name;
  String address;

  StoreInterface.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data)
    : name = data['name'],
      address = data['address'];
}
```

Use it like this:

```
StoreInterface data = StoreInterface.fromMap(snapshot.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that are still struggling with this problem, the solution is to cast piece by piece if you have a complex object type like `Map<String, List<SomeType>>`.

The DocumentSnapshot is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`, so as `dynamic` is a simple type, cannot be casted directly to a complex type having specific subtypes like `Map<String, List<SomeType>>`, but it must be casted to another simple type like `Map` without specific subtypes (or `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`).

After the first cast, you can use the `.map`/`.forEach` function to keep casting the two type of your `Map`.

In the example below I know the `data["state"]` is of type `Map<String, List<SomeType>>`.

Example:

```
Map<String, List<SomeType>> state = (data["state"] as Map).map((key, value) {
      List<SomeType> items = (value as List).map((e) => SomeType.fromMap(e)).toList();
      return MapEntry(key, items);
});
```

As you can see also the `value` parameter is a `dynamic` type, so you have to do the same thing as before, cast `value` to a simple type like `List` (or `List<dynamic>` and than cast/convert each item as you like.

Hope it helps.